# How do I troubleshoot crashing applications?

Tags: 8.0, twitter

The official Twitter application has begun crashing immediately after I launch it.

I have turned the device off and on again. But what else can I do to troubleshoot or correct such issues on Windows Phone 8? Reinstalling the application will be my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do unless the app developer has produced troubleshooting guides for known issues with their app.

- You can go check the app reviews in the store to see if other people are having this problem, or email the developer through the contact address listed in the store.
- If the app never worked for you, but others say it does work for them, do you have any settings on the phone that might be unusual, e.g; the device language or region format is not US-English? (It's easy for developers to miss errors caused by different region formats, although I'd be surprised if this happened for twitter).
- If the app previously worked and has just begun crashing, was there an update recently? Or have you changed any options on your phone like the device region?
- If the app suddenly stopped working and there was no update and no change on your phone, then it is quite likely there is a problem with the app settings/data saved on your phone - there could have been a bug in the app that saved an invalid value for your username, for instance. You cannot view the data saved by an application on your phone, so the only solution here is either an update from the developer that can recover the corrupt data (unlikely, if you cannot find other people hitting this problem), or for you to uninstall and reinstall the app, which will wipe the application data and allow it to run again.